# Java program not outputting correctly

Tags: java

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my code that I can't seem to figure out. Whenever I run this, it prints "Customer is null" instead of inserting their name. It also always calculates all tax as 0 (something wrong with my if statement?).
Is there any chance you guys can spot the issue? It seems as though everything else works correctly. (Wrote methods in Customer class, calling them in TestCustomer class, and the instructions are at the end of the post).

Thank you for anyone who takes the time to read this and attempt to help. Sorry for so much information, I just have no clue what is causing this, so I figured I'd include everything.

Customer class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Customer {
public static double taxRate = 0.00;
public static double saleRate = 0.00;
String customerName;
double listSaleAmount;
double saleDiscount = 0;
double netSaleAmount;
double taxAmount;
double saleTotal;
boolean taxable;
public double total;

public Customer (String customerName, boolean taxable) {

}

public void calculateTax () {
    saleDiscount = listSaleAmount*(saleRate/100);
    netSaleAmount = listSaleAmount-saleDiscount;

    if (taxable = true){
    taxAmount = netSaleAmount*(taxRate/100);
    }
    else{
        taxAmount = 0;
    }

    saleTotal = netSaleAmount + taxAmount;

    total += saleTotal;


}

public void printRecord () {
    System.out.println("Customer is " + customerName);
    System.out.println("Sale amount is $" + listSaleAmount);
    System.out.println("Discount amount is $" + saleDiscount);
    System.out.println("Net Sale Amount is $" + netSaleAmount);
    System.out.println("Tax amount is $" + taxAmount);
    System.out.println("Total Sale Amount is $" + saleTotal);
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static void changeTaxAmount () {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userTaxAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the Tax Rate? (8.25 & 8.50 for testing)"));
    taxRate = userTaxAmount;    
}

public static void changeSaleRate () {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userSaleAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the Sale Discount Rate? (0.00 & 7.50 for testing)"));
    saleRate= userSaleAmount;

}

public static void printTaxRate() {
    System.out.println("Tax Rate is " + taxRate + "%.");
}

public static void printSaleRate() {
    System.out.println("The Sale Rate is " + saleRate + ".");
    System.out.println(" ");
}
}
```

TestCustomer class

```
public class TestCustomer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Customer customer1 = new Customer("Annie Smith", true);
Customer customer2 = new Customer("Bob Wilson", false);


Customer.changeTaxAmount();

Customer.printTaxRate();


Customer.changeSaleRate();

Customer.printSaleRate();

customer1.listSaleAmount = 65.00;
customer2.listSaleAmount = 52.00;


customer1.calculateTax();
customer1.printRecord();

customer2.calculateTax();
customer2.printRecord();


Customer.changeTaxAmount();
Customer.printTaxRate();
Customer.changeSaleRate();
Customer.printSaleRate();

customer1.listSaleAmount = 84.00;
customer2.listSaleAmount = 105.00;
customer1.calculateTax();
customer1.printRecord();
customer2.calculateTax();
customer2.printRecord();

double total2 = customer1.total + customer2.total;
System.out.println("The total of all sales is $" + total2);
    }

}
```

Assignment sheet (Not worrying about printing to a file right now, just want the main mechanics to work)
[image]
[image]

Also, thank you to those of you who helped me with my last question on this project. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your constructor in customer class to set values of customerName and texable class level variables:

```
public Customer (String customerName, boolean taxable) {
  this.customerName = customerName;
  this.taxable = taxable;
}
```

Also, there seems to be problem with the below if condition:

```
if (taxable = true){
```

You should use == operator for comparing:

```
if (taxable == true) {
```

Actually, you don't need to compare it. Just use:

```
if (taxable) {
```

Comment: Thank you! Two little stupid mistakes that I just kept overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor

```
public Customer (String customerName, boolean taxable) {

}
```

You are passed in parameters, but you never assign them to your class fields.

try

```
public Customer (String customerName, boolean taxable) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.taxable = taxable;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this! Thank you. My tax, however, is still calculating incorrectly (now it's calculating tax regardless, but it's supposed to be tax-free for Bob Wilson). Do you have any idea why that would be?EDIT: Nevermind, Akshay found it!

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor in Customer class should assign the name and taxable value to Customer data member.

```
public Customer (String customerName, boolean taxable) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.taxable = taxable;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this! Thank you. My tax, however, is still calculating incorrectly (now it's calculating tax for everything, but it's supposed to be tax-free for Bob Wilson). Do you have any idea why that would be? EDIT: Nevermind, Akshay found it!

Comment: your if statements should use '==' instead of just '=' :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if (taxable = true)`, simply use `if (taxable)`.